# 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized error while trying to create a SMTP client

Tags: python, smtp, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I am trying to create a SMTP client that uses GMX mail service in order to send an email to my original gmail account.
I started exploring about SMTP protocol, and I got the main idea. 
While trying to implement the client I get an error

> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized

As you can see the AUTH process completed successfully, so the email and password and correct. But it doesn't let me send the email from my account.

**Here is the full code:**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("smtp.gmx.com",25))

s.send("EHLO gmx\r\n") 
print s.recv(10000);


s.send("AUTH PLAIN dHN0QGdteC5jb21QYXNzd29yZCE=\r\n")
print s.recv(10000);

print "1"
s.send("MAIL FROM:<tst@gmx.com>\r\n")
print s.recv(10000);
print "2"
s.send("RCPT TO:tst@gmail.com\r\n")

print s.recv(10000);

s.send("QUIT\r\n")
```

**And here is the full result:**

> 220 gmx.com (mrgmx101) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
>
> 250-gmx.com Hello gmx [87.68.73.54]
>  250-SIZE 69920427
>  250-AUTH LOGIN
>   PLAIN 
> 250 STARTTLS
>
> 1 
>  500 Syntax error, command unrecognized
>
> 2
>  503 Bad sequence of commands

Answer (score 0):

I have got `535 Authentication credentials invalid` reply after adding separate fetching of SMTP greeting message.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("smtp.gmx.com",25))
print s.recv(10000);    

s.send("EHLO gmx\r\n") 
print s.recv(10000);


s.send("AUTH PLAIN dHN0QGdteC5jb21QYXNzd29yZCE=\r\n")
print s.recv(10000);
```

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I didn't my account to be posted,so I changed the email & password to something else.  When I have entered my original email and password I received a proper reply message from the server.

Comment: I have not expected you to include real password :-) . Anyway: Your initial code had not triggered any `AUTH`specific reply from the server.